# How to visualize (and understand) transposed convolutions?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, deconvolution

I have seen two ways of visualizing transposed convolutions from credible sources, and as far as I can see they conflict.

My question boils down to, for each application of the kernel, do we go from many (e.g. `3x3`) elements with input padding to one, or do we go from one element to many (e.g. `3x3`)?

*Related question:* Which version does [tf.nn.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) implement?

**The sources of my confusion are:**

---

[A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285) has probably the most famous visualization out there, but it isn't peer reviewed (Arxiv).

[image]

---

The second is from [Deconvolution and Checkerboard Artifacts](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/), which technically isn't peer reviewed either (Distil), but it is from a much more reputable source.
(The term deconvolution is used in the article, but it is stated that this is the same as transposed conv.)

[image]

---

Due to the nature of this question it is hard to look for results online, e.g. this [SO](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) posts takes the first position, but I am not sure to what extent I can trust it.

Comment: Actually distil publications are peer reviewed, and the process is quite strict...

Answer (score 3):

Strided convolutions, deconvolutions, transposed convolutions all mean the same thing. Both papers are correct and you don't need to be doubtful as both of them are [cited](https://scholar.google.com/) a lot. But the distil image is from a different perspective as its trying to show the artifacts problem.

The first visualisation is transposed convolutions with stride 2 and padding 1. If it was stride 1, there wouldn't be any padding in between inputs. The padding on the borders depend on the dimension of the output.

By deconvolution, we generally go from a smaller dimension to a higher dimension. And input data is generally padded to achieve the desired output dimensions. I believe the confusion arises from the padding patterns. Take a look at this formula

```
output = [(input-1)stride]+kernel_size-2*padding_of_output
```

Its a rearrangement of the general convolution output formula. Output here refers to the output of the deconvolution operation. To best understand deconvolution, I suggest thinking in terms of the equation, i.e., flipping what a convolution does. Its asking how do I reverse what a convolution operation does?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand the layer-wise dynamics, but at the operational level I am still not sure. For every application of the kernel how big is the input receptive field?

Comment: Strided convolution is distinct from transposed convolution. Also, transposed conv doesn't reverse what conv does, it basically corresponds to the gradient operation of conv.

Comment: Although "deconvolution" and "transposed convolution" are often used in a similar way, they are [_not_ the same thing](https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-717013397f4d)!

Comment: PS: Please don't call it a deconvolution

Answer (score 3):

I want to stress a little more what Littleone also mentioned in his last paragraph:

**A transposed convolution will reverse the spatial transformation of a regular convolution with the same parameters.**

If you perform a regular convolution followed by a transposed convolution and both have the same settings (kernel size, padding, stride), then the input and output will have the same shape. This makes it super easy to build encoder-decoder networks with them. I wrote an article about different types of convolutions in Deep Learning [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-717013397f4d), where this is also covered.

PS: Please don't call it a deconvolution

Answer (score 1):

Good explanation from Justin Johnson (part of the Stanford cs231n mooc):

https://youtu.be/ByjaPdWXKJ4?t=1221 (starts at 20:21)

He reviews strided conv and then he explains transposed convolutions.

[image]